# Using MySQL to change value output/trim all text before and after certain value

Tags: mysql

Currently trying to transform some text in MySQL. Could use some help since I'm running into some problems trying to use some aggregate functions.

I've got a column `stay` that's got values that I can use for the most part, but I've got instances where the output is `More than 100 Days`. I'm currently trying to get rid of everything but the 100. I've tried using `TRIM` functions, but I haven't had any luck. I can only get rid of either `More than` or `Days` but not both. I also know I can't use `TRIM(BOTH)` since the text before and after 100 is different.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What does `SELECT @@VERSION` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might come across pretty unorthodox but how about making use of datetime functions:

```
SELECT t.stay,
    -- actual logic to fetch the digits
    (DATEDIFF(
        STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT((@var_some_year := 1000), t.stay),
            -- the pattern
            '%YMore than %j Days'
        ),
        MAKEDATE(@var_some_year, 1)) + 1
    ) AS Digits
FROM
(
    -- mimicinf your table
    SELECT CONCAT('More than ', (@var:= @var + 1), ' Days') AS stay
    FROM (SELECT @var:= 0) twofold0
    JOIN (SELECT NULL UNION ALL SELECT NULL) twofold1
    JOIN (SELECT NULL UNION ALL SELECT NULL) twofold2
    JOIN (SELECT NULL UNION ALL SELECT NULL) twofold3
    JOIN (SELECT NULL UNION ALL SELECT NULL) twofold4
    JOIN (SELECT NULL UNION ALL SELECT NULL) twofold5
    JOIN (SELECT NULL UNION ALL SELECT NULL) twofold6
    JOIN (SELECT NULL UNION ALL SELECT NULL) twofold7
    JOIN (SELECT NULL UNION ALL SELECT NULL) twofold8
    JOIN (SELECT NULL UNION ALL SELECT NULL) twofold9
    JOIN (SELECT NULL UNION ALL SELECT NULL) twofold10
) t
;
```

Seems to work for up to 4 digit patterns.